# Questions about "Import Image as Plane "

Tags: image

I brought the .mp4 and .avi video files on the plane.
It played and stopped as long as it is set.
Is there a way to repeat this indefinitely?(maybe loop?)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

in materials properties tab, Alpha opion then you can click on cyclic button